# PHP Time/Date Timezone Specific Stuff

Tags: php, date, time, timezone, unix-timestamp

I'm slightly curious as to how I can store and access 'time points' for various things while acquiring a user's timezone. It would be cool to use `time();` as the storage / database data.

For example if I make an update to a blog it would show the stamp as something like `26/01/2000 11:34` but if the user's timezone was one hour ahead of mine then it would appear as `26/01/2000 12:34`, of course determined through their settings. It would also be useful for things like countdowns for time limited features. I however do not know how to format the unix-timestamp in this way. Guidance and help would be wonderful :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your post times and server time should be UTC to start.
Retrieve your post time from the DB and utilize the DateTime and DateTimeZone classes in some way similar to below

```
$fromDatabase = '2008-08-03 14:52:10';
$datetime = new DateTime($fromDatabase);
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$datetime->setTimeZone($timezone);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Alternatively on Linux if using MySQL you can load the timezone tables and adjust the date time returned in the MySQL query. Refer to this page for how to start with this - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Answer (score 1):

Please read the manual page on the date:

[PHP Manual: Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

I believe this code will do what you asked:

```
$time = time();
$today = date("m j, Y, G:i a");
echo $today;
```

To change time zones, add or subtract an hour. Since unix timestamps are in seconds, 60 seconds x 60 minutes = 1 hour, or 360 seconds. So add 360 seconds to move one hour ahead, subtract o go one hour back, like this:

```
$time = time()-360;
```

Comment: From what i know if you want more accuracy you can [get the time in milliseconds in PHP](http://currentmillis.com) by using microtime(true) which returns seconds but as a float value which you can then multiply with 1000 for millis: round(microtime(true) * 1000)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for reposting my answer here and on another time question.

This will work with any time formatted as 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' (and probably any time that can be used by the "new DateTime" functions.

```
function changetimefromUTC($time, $timezone) {                   // SEND YOUR ORIGINAL TIME AND YOUR NEW TIMEZONE
    $changetime = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));  //YOUR ORIGINAL TIME GOES HERE
    $changetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));       // THIS CHANGES TO THE NEW TIMEZONE
    return $changetime->format('m/d/y h:i a');    // THIS OUTPUTS THE NEW TIME IN WHATEVER FORMAT YOU WANT
}
```

list of supported times zones  https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php